# Complex custom collection join and where problem

Tags: module, attributes, magento-1, filter, custom-attributes

I am making a custom filter to show products in varying quantities of stock (both actually in warehouse and stock I have on back-order).

Below is my apply function:

```
public function apply(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, $filterBlock)
{
    $filter = (int) $request->getParam($this->getRequestVar());
    if (!$filter || Mage::registry('mynamespace_filter_filter')) {
        return $this;
    }

    //add actual stock levels
    $select = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
        ->joinField('qty','cataloginventory/stock_item','qty',
             'product_id=entity_id','{{table}}.stock_id=1','left')
        ->getSelect()
    //add theoretical stock levels
        ->join(
            array('ea' => 'eav_attribute'),
            '`e`.`entity_type_id` = `ea`.`entity_type_id` AND `ea`.`attribute_code` = "theoretical_stock"',
            '*'
        )
        ->join(
            array('ce_int' => 'catalog_product_entity_varchar'),
            '`e`.`entity_id` = `ce_int`.`entity_id` AND `ea`.`attribute_id` = `ce_int`.`attribute_id` AND `ea`.`backend_type` = "varchar"',
            array('theoretical_stock' => 'ce_int.value')
        );
    /* @var $select Zend_Db_Select */

    //add where clause that compares qty vs theoretical_stock
    switch($filter) {
        case self::FILTER_IN_STOCK:
            $select->where('`qty` > 255');
            $stateLabel = Mage::helper('mynamespace_filter')->__('In Stock');
            break;
        case self::FILTER_LIMITED_STOCK:
            $select->where('`qty` > 0 && `qty` <= 255');
            $stateLabel = Mage::helper('mynamespace_filter')->__('Limited Stock');
            break;
        case self::FILTER_PRE_ORDER_STOCK:
            $select->where('`qty` = 0 && `theoretical_stock` > 0');
            $stateLabel = Mage::helper('mynamespace_filter')->__('Pre Order Stock');
            break;
    }

    //create state item
    $state = $this->_createItem(
        $stateLabel, $filter
    )->setVar($this->_requestVar);
    /* @var $state Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item */

    $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($state);

    Mage::register('mynamespace_filter_filter', true);

    return $this;
}
```

My issue is being caused by the collection being passed around by reference, and my join and where being called for random other stuff. For some requests the field I am asking for in one of my joins (`theoretical_stock`) is being removed so the where clause suddenly fails and throws an exception.

How do I rewrite the above so I can filter my products by my custom attribute (the two `join`s) without it failing when the collection is passed to the next function?

[edit]

Here is the error log:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:1222:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.entity_type_id' in 'on clause', query was: SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '40'
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_at_qty` ON (at_at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_at_qty.stock_id=1)
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
 INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `ea` ON `e`.`entity_type_id` = `ea`.`entity_type_id` AND `ea`.`attribute_code` = "theoretical_stock"
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `ce_int` ON `e`.`entity_id` = `ce_int`.`entity_id` AND `ea`.`attribute_id` = `ce_int`.`attribute_id` AND `ea`.`backend_type` = "varchar" WHERE (`at_qty`.`qty` = 0 && `ce_int`.`value` = 0) AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 ORDER BY FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 ASC";i:1;s:4661:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(811): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Layer\Filter\Price.php(282): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price.php(158): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price->getCount(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price), 10)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getRangeItemCounts(10)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price.php(314): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getPriceRange()
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Abstract.php(151): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->_getItemsData()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Abstract.php(120): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initItems()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\Filter\Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\layer\view.phtml(49): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\\base\\d...')
#17 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Text\List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#23 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\design\frontend\project\default\template\page\2columns-left.phtml(30): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#24 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#25 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend\\project\\de...')
#26 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\controllers\CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#32 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#33 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 C:\xampp\htdocs\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}";s:3:"url";s:58:"/small-appliances/kitchen-electricals/kettles.html?stock=4";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

As you can see, the join and where have persisted to another filter (`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price`).

Comment: So, are you saying your `$select` fails outside of this method? I don't see how `theoretical_stock` can be removed within this method. Can you also post your error?

Answer (score 0):

- There might be a strong case that your attribute '**theoretical_stock**' is not assigned to all the **attribute sets**
- Double check that attribute '**theoretical_stock**' exists in all attribute sets (attribute sets that are assigned to your products)
- This might be a reasson in some of your cases that the field is not found and removed from join

Comment: I've checked and it is assigned to all attribute sets. Looking into the exception stack dump, it is loading the _getCount function in the price filter. So the price filter is using the same collection (and joins) as my collection.

Comment: Please share the error with us

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem. I believe the issue is that `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price` is cloning the existing collection then modifying it as it needs. Once you add your own filters or attributes it's still picking up on those and those obviously don't exist anymore so the query fails. To fix this, you need to override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price`

Example: I added a **"publish_date"** attribute so that products would not show until a certain date, then added a filter for that attribute so that any time a product collection is loaded it will ignore products that shouldn't be published yet...

```
$this->_productCollection
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute' => 'publish_date', 'to' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()),
            array('attribute' => 'publish_date', 'null' => true)
        ),
        'left'
    );
```

So naturally, when the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price` sees this, it's going to clone this collection and that field isn't going to be in whatever table it's looking up. To fix that, I overrode `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price` with a custom class, and changed the `_getSelect()` method with something to fix this. Not a great solution, but it seems to work for all product collections which is nice.

```
// processing WHERE part
$wherePart = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
foreach ($wherePart as $key => $wherePartItem) {
    if (strpos($wherePartItem, "publish_date") !== false)
    {
        unset($wherePart[$key]);
        continue;
    }

    $wherePart[$key] = $this->_replaceTableAlias($wherePartItem);
}
```